# php form is not submitting values in the database

Tags: php, mysql, html

I made a form that has 26 fields including 6 images. Using the PHP language, I am submitting the the form using input type submit, then all the values are posted but entry in the database is not done.

It shows this error: `G:\xampp\tmp\php9506.tmp`

In the error, the number written in PHP, `9506`, is random number, it changes each time I try to submit the form.

My database and connection file is correct.

What could the possible reasons for this be?

```
<?php
 include "header.php";
 include "left.php";

 $busi_cat = $_GET['mcatname'];



 if(isset($_POST) && $_POST['add'] == "Add")
 {


extract($_POST);

 $adver_type = implode(',',$adver_type);
 echo $busi_cat = $_GET['mcatname'];

if ($_FILES["photo1"]['tmp_name'] != "")
    {
        if(! file_exists("images/client"))
        {
        mkdir("images/client"); 
        }
        echo $source = $_FILES["photo1"]['tmp_name'];
        $photo1 = "images/client/".$_FILES["photo1"]['name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($source, $photo1))
        {
            echo "image uploaded  succesfully"; 
        }
        else
        {
            echo "problem in uploading";    
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "please select a photo";   
    }

    if ($_FILES["photo2"]['tmp_name'] != "")
    {
        if(! file_exists("images/client"))
        {
        mkdir("images/client"); 
        }

        $source = $_FILES["photo2"]['tmp_name'];
        $photo2 = "images/client/".$_FILES["photo2"]['name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($source, $photo2))
        {
            echo "image uploaded  succesfully"; 
        }
        else
        {
            echo "problem in uploading";    
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "please select a photo";   
    }

    if ($_FILES["photo3"]['tmp_name'] != "")
    {
        if(! file_exists("images/client"))
        {
        mkdir("images/client"); 
        }

        $source = $_FILES["photo3"]['tmp_name'];
        $photo3 = "images/client/".$_FILES["photo3"]['name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($source, $photo3))
        {
            echo "image uploaded  succesfully"; 
        }
        else
        {
            echo "problem in uploading";    
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "please select a photo";   
    }

    if ($_FILES["photo4"]['tmp_name'] != "")
    {
        if(! file_exists("images/client"))
        {
        mkdir("images/client"); 
        }

        $source = $_FILES["photo4"]['tmp_name'];
        $photo4 = "images/client/".$_FILES["photo4"]['name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($source, $photo4))
        {
            echo "image uploaded  succesfully"; 
        }
        else
        {
            echo "problem in uploading";    
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "please select a photo";   
    }

    if ($_FILES["photo5"]['tmp_name'] != "")
    {
        if(! file_exists("images/client"))
        {
        mkdir("images/client"); 
        }

        $source = $_FILES["photo5"]['tmp_name'];
        $photo5 = "images/client/".$_FILES["photo5"]['name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($source, $photo5))
        {
            echo "image uploaded  succesfully"; 
        }
        else
        {
            echo "problem in uploading";    
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "please select a photo";   
    }

    if ($_FILES["photo6"]['tmp_name'] != "")
    {
        if(! file_exists("images/client"))
        {
        mkdir("images/client"); 
        }

        $source = $_FILES["photo6"]['tmp_name'];
        $photo6 = "images/client/".$_FILES["photo6"]['name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($source, $photo6))
        {
            echo "image uploaded  succesfully"; 
        }
        else
        {
            echo "problem in uploading";    
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "please select a photo";   
    }




echo $query = "INSERT INTO register(busi_name, busi_cat, busi_scat, oth_busi_cat, addr, cont_per, phone, mobile, emailid, website, deal, keyword, message, adver_plan, photo1, photo2, photo3, photo4, photo5, photo6, status, full_page)VALUES('$busi_name', '$busi_cat', '$busi_scat', '$oth_busi_cat', '$addr', '$cont_per', '$phone', '$mobile', '$emailid', '$website', '$deal', '$keyword', '$message','$adver_type','$photo1','$photo2','$photo3','$photo4','$photo5','$photo6','0', '0')";
$res = mysql_query($query);
if($res)
    {
        $msg = "Your Business Added Successfully.";
    }
  }
   ?>
```

Comment: I guess it's the color of your sweater, try to change it then tell us!

Comment: php submitting code? its very lengthy.

Comment: @atultyagi Just post the relevant parts - if folks want more, they will ask for extra detail :)

Comment: @moonwave99 It could be the color of the sweater, but sometimes its the pattern of my tie. So to the OP, your results may vary.

Comment: @Fluffeh didn't understand :)

Comment: http://www.hybridsols.com/demo/tnm/advertisement.php?mcatname=Book%20Shops

Comment: the random no you are talking about is the temporary name of image that you are uploading

Comment: ohh, Hi to you to :), nice to see you :)

Comment: @techie_28  but i haven't face this problem when i uploaded the image earlier.

Comment: Why some hilarious and funny comments over here?Specific reason or something?

Comment: @techie_28  form is not inserting the values in the database, after submission - error message appear that i mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are using `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`.
Try `$_POST['element name']`

I think the problem is in [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function.

Comment: Suggesting a `$_REQUEST` would have been better (takes either) but either way, this is more of a comment than an answer, I know you are keen to help, but folks here are pretty strict about *non answer* answers if that makes sense.

Comment: @YogiYogesh i have posted the code also.

Comment: @atultyagi you are using $_GET for busi_cat.

Comment: @YogiYogesh yes, but when i use $_REQUEST then even its not inserting the values.

Comment: remove the extract line. May be it is causing problem.

Comment: no, extract is important alse no values will be posted

Comment: you can get value using $_POST['element name']. so why are you using extract. Just see the posted link and try with it.

Comment: this was the database access problem. i talked to the server service provider and they resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

`echo $query = "INSERT I....`

Remove the `echo` from this line. This is what is printed when you see the "random number".

If you want to print the query (not recommended), add `echo $query;` *after* the `$query = "INSERT` line.

Also, please use [`mysqli`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [prepared statements](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: The next version of the MySQL libraries for PHP. See http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php